# How to keep highlight of listview item after device orientation changes in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview, android-listview

I have a listview which is populated with data. The user can long press a certain row and it will be highlighted and also the contextual action bar will show that it is selected. If the user selects more rows, the number of rows selected increases in the contextual action bar. However, once I change the orientation of the device, the highlights go away but the list items are shown as selected. I have tried using selectors but it didn't help. In the XML, I have made each row have the activatedBackgroundIndicator as its background.

Does anyone know why the highlights disappear? Thanks.

Here is the onSaveInstanceState code:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    //check if any items are selected
    if (listView.getCheckedItemCount() > 0) {
        //get the list of selected items and convert it to an int Array
        //because SparseBooleanArray cannot be stored in a bundle
        SparseBooleanArray selectedItems = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();
        int[] selectedItems_intArray = new int[listView.getCheckedItemCount()];
        for (int i = 0; i < selectedItems.size(); i++) {
            if (selectedItems.valueAt(i) == false)
                continue;
            selectedItems_intArray[i] = selectedItems.keyAt(i);
        }
        outState.putIntArray("Selected Items", selectedItems_intArray);
    }
}
```

Here is the code in the onCreate:

```
       if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            int[] checkedItems = savedInstanceState.getIntArray("Selected Items");
            if (checkedItems != null) {

                for (int i = 0; i < checkedItems.length; i++) {
                   listView.setItemChecked(checkedItems[i], true);
                    adapter.setNewSelection(checkedItems[i], true);

                }
            }
        }
```

EDIT:

Here is the  section of the listview activity:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.newapp.MainListActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you rotate de the device, the current activity gets destroyed and recreated.

You can store the selected element on onPause() and then select it in onResume(), or you can use the much simpler solution: don't allow Android to destroy your activity when the device rotates.

For that, you can add into the AndroidManifest to the section of that activity:

```
<activity android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
...
</activity>
```

Note: you can also do the same for the whole application (adding the same `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` into the `application` section), if you want to.

edit:

My first answer consisted on using `android:configChanges="orientation"`. My second one consisted on using `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`.

For those wondering why, the thing is quite simple:

1. Adding that `orientation` to the manifest, you are telling Android "don't worry about orientation changes, I can handle it". So, when the orientation of the device changes, Android doesn't worry about destroying and recreating the activity.
2. Adding that `screenSize` to the manifest, you are telling Android "don't worry about screen size changes, I can handle it". This shouldn't be necessary in our case, but it can be. The reason is that some versions of Android (I can't really recall which ones) are kinda stupid about this. When you have a device on vertical position, it has 480x800 pixels; when you have it in horizontal position, it has 800x480 pixels. So, the screen size **did** change. Some versions of Android are clever enough to identify that kind of "screen size change" so they consider it part of the `android:configChanges="orientation"`setting; some Android versions are not that clever and you have to specify both.

Note: when you use this kind of technique, be aware that Android won't handle the device rotation. So, if you have a different layout for portrait mode and lanscape mode, you will have to change it yourself (but I would suggest just not to use this method, even if it is easier for apps with only one layout type).

Comment: I have already tried that but it didn't work. To test how I can highlight a listview item with no click interaction I used this code in my onCreate(): `listView.getOnItemLongClickListener().onItemLongClick(null, listView, 1, listView.getItemIdAtPosition(1));` This line checks the desired listview item and my contextual action bar shows that its checked, however, the item is not highlighted. How can I highlight the listview item the same way it normally highlights when the user physically presses and holds on the listview item?

Comment: You say you tried `android:configChanges="orientation"` without that code from above and it didn't work? Can I see the complete `<activity>` section of the relevant activity?

Comment: Yes that's correct. I pasted thee <activity> section above in the question.

Comment: I remembered that in some api versions you might need to use `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`. It is worth trying (without the `onSaveInstanceState` piece of code).

Comment: No way! It works! Do you mind telling me why it works?

Comment: Yeah, of course. I'll put a little explanation in the answer. Congrats!

Comment: How would I use code to obtain the same result as using the `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`? With code, I have saved the number of checked items in the listview, however, the highlight is gone.